# Why console giving me result undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

I Don't khow why my console is telling me that the result is undefined.I am learning DOM and found the problem on my first code which i don't understand

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>

        let head = document.getElementsByClassName(".main");

        console.log(head.textContent);

        let tail = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

        console.log(tail.textContent);

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because A) the elements do not exist yet and B) these functions return a list not an element.

Comment: At the time you're calling this script, the document hasn't fully loaded, so there is no main class or p tag yet. You can move your script tag below the body or wrap them in a function and set them to run when the DOM has loaded.

BTW, you don't need the `.` to indicate your class name when you use `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: in addition, you need to pass in `main`, not `.main`.

Comment: thanks for your response and i applied your method but still it's undefined ....

Answer (score 0):

1. The elements doesn´t exist when the script runs in head. Move the script to after the elements
2. Change from `.main` to `main` in `getElementsByClassName`
3. `getElementsByClassName` returns a list so add `[0]` to `getElementsByClassName("main")` to get the first element

```html
<div class="main">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>

<script>
    let head = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];
    console.log(head.textContent);

    let tail = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    console.log(tail.textContent);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Move your script to the body
- `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of HTML elements, not a single element
- with `document.getElementsByClassName` you should pass `main`, not `.main`
- the textContent of the div with class `main` is probably not what you expect
- to get an single element by its class name or its tag name, you can also use `querySelector` which is more simple (but slower)
  Here is a working version :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
  
        <script>
            let head = document.querySelector(".main");
            console.log(head.textContent);
            let tail = document.querySelector("p");
            console.log(tail.textContent);
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```